# Invalid column name using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to minus the value from `POSquantity` to `iPay88quantity` but I get an error

> Invalid column name

My code:

```
select distinct
    tblCurrTrxIPAY88.strAmount as IPay88,
    tblCurrTrxIPAY88.strPOSOnlineRefNo,
    count(tblCurrTrxIPAY88.strPOSOnlineRefNo) as iPay88quantity,
    b.strCostCentreID,
    b.strPOSOnlineRefNo, 
    count(b.strPOSOnlineRefNo) as POSquantity,
    strPayTypeCode, b.strRemarks as Agency,
    tblMachine.strDesc As KioskName, 
    SUM(b.dblPaidAmt) as POS24,
    SUM(b.dblPaidAmt) - tblCurrTrxIPAY88.strAmount as RMVarince,
    POSquantity - iPay88quantity as Varince
from 
    tblCurrTrxMaster as b
inner join
    tblMachine on b.strMachID = tblMachine.strMachID 
inner join
    tblCurrTrxIPAY88 on b.strPOSOnlineRefNo = tblCurrTrxIPAY88.strPOSOnlineRefNo
where
    strPaymentMethod = '02' 
    and b.dtmCreated >= '1/23/2020' 
    and b.strTransStatus = '01'
group by 
    b.strCostCentreID , b.strPOSOnlineRefNo, b.strPayTypeCode, b.strRemarks, 
    tblMachine.strDesc, tblCurrTrxIPAY88.strAmount, 
    tblCurrTrxIPAY88.strPOSOnlineRefNo
```

Comment: Please provide the Tables Schema.

Comment: I really suggest using aliases, and making good use white space and line breaks; that code is very difficult to read. Also use appropriate aliases, not just any old letter. "b" is for `tblCurrTrxMaster`? `CTM` would seem far more appropriate. Good code formatting won't just anyone who has to read the code, that includes you, will find it far easier to understand, debug and modify.

Comment: For the second time, remove distinct as it does nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPay88Quantity is not a column name in your table,  it is a calculated field - you need to do the math on the underlying fields, not the computed field, i.e:

```
POSquantity - count(tblCurrTrxIPAY88.strPOSOnlineRefNo) as Variance
```

Comment: Thanks, its work.                                                                  
                                                                                             
count(b.strPOSOnlineRefNo) - count(tblCurrTrxIPAY88.strPOSOnlineRefNo) as Variance